# Using vuejs 3 and modules with DOM prerendered by PHP without compilation

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs3

In a current project I work with the fatfreeframwork PHP Microframework. The pages contain recurring sections on multiple pages that only differ in the data displayed. Each of this sections is associated with a plain javascript file to handle interactions.

So far so good, everything works just fine. As I am now delving into vuejs 3 I would like replace my Javascript Code, which mostly consists of DOM manipulation when users interact, with vuejs.

This works fine if I treat the page as a single page app. Because of the repeating sections in many pages I now have a lot of code duplication in my beginner vuejs code for each page, because I define the same functionality over and over again in different pages.

I would like to define my page as an app, load vue modules as independent js files (if possible without build step) and get the template string for the modules from the prerendered page. In general, treat vuejs like jquery from olden times.

Is it possible in vuejs to get a modules template from the prerendered page, or must I  duplicate the code in a modules template? From a vue beginner perspective, is there maybe a better way to integrate vuejs into an existing PHP application without too much code duplication?

[image: current state of application]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with x-templates. These allow me to minimally alter existing HTML Code and keep it in the PHP codebase. I have to make sure that the runtime template compiler of vuejs is included.

x-templates are defined in HTML via script tag:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="componentTemplate1"> ... </script>
```

I know it is not the best way to work with vuejs, but it is the best way for me to integrate view into an existing PHP app.